# Why is my Vue-ChartJS Chart data is not showing on ie10?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-chartjs

I am using the pre-packaged script files from vue and vue-chartjs, and adding them to the page.

Initially no view was working and after opening the dev tools on ie10 I saw that the es6 stuff like `=>`, `let` and `myFunc(): ....` were breaking the page.

So I removed this and now the outline and layout of the chart shows and the axes proportions even change when new data is acquired. However no content is actually showing up in the charts.

My suspicion is that it is this new `html` tag, that ie does not recognise:

```
 <line-chart
  :data="myData"
  :options="{responsive: false, maintainAspectRatio: false}"
  :width="400"
  :height="200"
  >
 </line-chart>
```

**Update**:

The `getQueueData` function to get data from API

```
getQueueData: function() {
            var selectedBranch = this.selectedBranch;
            var selectedDay = this.selectedDay;
            var vm = this;
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/branches/' + selectedBranch + '/queues/' + selectedDay + '/').then(function(response) {
                vm.queueData = response.body;
                vm.fillData();
            }, function(response) {
                alert('Whoops! Something went wrong.')
                vm.queueData = [];
            });
        },
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle/codepen? Because I've got the following example running in ie10
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaLJXq?editors=1010

Comment: Here is the pen, unforunately it works as expected: https://codepen.io/surfer190/pen/XaLEqR See in the `getQueueData` function I am using Vue Resource to actually get the data and I can't make that request in codepen. I have added the actualy code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well chartjs and vue and vue-chartjs are working fine in IE10.
It depends on your workflow and pipeline. Javascript should be transpiled. And the  is not a new html tag, it is a custom element for vue.js.

However I guess your problem is more the API call. Because the api call is async. So you open your page where the chart is, and the chart gets rendered before your data arrives.

You could set a variable like `loaded` or something and only render the chart if your data arrvied.

```
<line-chart
  v-if="loaded"
  :data="myData"
  :options="{responsive: false, maintainAspectRatio: false}"
  :width="400"
  :height="200"
  >
 </line-chart>



getQueueData: function() {
            var selectedBranch = this.selectedBranch;
            var selectedDay = this.selectedDay;
            var vm = this;
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/branches/' + selectedBranch + '/queues/' + selectedDay + '/').then(function(response) {
                vm.queueData = response.body;
                vm.fillData();
                vm.loaded = true
            }, function(response) {
                alert('Whoops! Something went wrong.')
                vm.queueData = [];
            });
        },
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work the data did not show up. Please check it out at http://sars-queue.fixes.co.za/